Reconstruct images from patches after every epoch
I have a large image that I split into small equal patches. I load these patches into a model. After prediction, I try to reconstruct the patches to form the shape of input image.
batch_size = 20 # select number of patches
epochs = 15

for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    label_as_fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1)) 
    label_as_real = np.ones((batch_size,1)) 
   
    for ii in tqdm(range(len(train_hr_batches))): #total patches, 100
        lr_imgs = train_lr_batches[ii] 
        hr_imgs = train_hr_batches[ii] 
        
        generated_patches = generator.predict_on_batch(lr_imgs)

Call the reconstruction function to save images
if (epoch+1) % 1 ==0:
 reconstructed_sr = reconstruct_patches(generated_patches, image_height, image_width, patch_height, patch_width) 
 save_images(reconstructed_sr, f'reconstructed_sr_epoch_{epoch+1}.TIF')


I can save the the individual 100 generated patches after an epoch. However, when I try to put together patches to reconstruct an image to the shape of the input image, there is an error suggesting that the model is trying to reconstruct the image after a single iteration (i.e., after 20 patches). How do I modify the code to do a complete run on the 100 patches before trying to reconstruct the images?
Cell In[39], line 7
    reconstructed_sr = reconstruct_patches(generated_images, image_height, image_width, patch_height, patch_width)

  Cell In[37], line 12 in reconstruct_patches
    raise ValueError(f"expected {expected_num_patches} patches but found {actual_num_patches} patches")

ValueError: expected 100 patches but found 20 patches

Code attempting to reconstruct images only after the end of a defined batch_size

please provide some context and clarity ([ask]). please provide a [mre].
